# Concurvity in parametric terms in GAM in R with mgcv

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, model-fitting

I have a GAM model (below) where SST_mean and NAO are numerical values, and cycle and region are categorical factors. I checked for concurvity using the concurvity function in mgcv.

```
m2 <- gam(Strandings ~ s(SST_mean) + s(NAO, bs="re") + Cycle + Region, 
      family=poisson, data=DAT_ST, method = "REML")
```

The initial results below had quite high values suggesting there is concurvity in the model.

```
> concurvity(m2, full = TRUE)
                     para     s(SST_mean)  s(NAO)
          worst    0.8944583  0.7532177   0.7131497
          observed 0.8944583  0.5784295   0.7131497
          estimate 0.8944583  0.5309899   0.7131497
```

I ran pairwise comparisons and it looks like the concurvity issues are actually between the parametric terms not between the smoothed terms or between the smoothed terms and the parametric

```
 > concurvity(m2, full = FALSE)
 $worst
                para        s(SST_mean)    s(NAO)
 para        1.000000e+00   1.736827e-25   0.001064966
 s(SST_mean) 1.746022e-25   1.000000e+00   0.351366528
 s(NAO)      1.064966e-03   3.513665e-01   1.000000000
```

Is there any reason for this, and is this an issue for my models. Or because the parametrics are categorical, is this to be expected for some reason? Someone I read that above 0.8 indicates concurvity that should be addressed but I can't find any specific thresholds in the literature. Are there any references people could recommend please?